# How do I set the default language of an Android App? (Appcelerator)

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm currently developing an Android app with Appcelerator which is only in Spanish.

My problem is that if the user doesn't have its smartphone in Spanish, strings from strings.xml won't show:

[image: strings.xml missing]

How do I set Spanish as the default language of my app? I found a solution on the Appcelerator wiki, but it's just for iOS https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Internationalization#Internationalization-Setdefaultlanguage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is the default translation for all Titanium apps, therefore the English files are mandatory. If you just add the English folder to your i18n directory (inside the app directory) you should be good.

If your app is only going to be in Spanish, just add Spanish to that directory and everything should work everywhere.

There is a ticket in the Appcelerator JIRA for adding support, there is also a way to override in the comments: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20527

Comment: I just have the i18n/es/strings.xml file, but if I try to run the app on a Smartphone that has a different language, no strings will be shown.

I tried setting the system language as English on a Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 6.0) emulator and on my BQ Aquaris E5 4G (Android 5.1) and I'm facing the same problem on both devices: I can't see the strings.

Comment: the files are mandatory in the `en` directory. Just put them in there as well as in the `es` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear. You can always join http://tislack.org to join the Ti community on slack, and ask questions in the helpme channel ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, adding a translation in another language. Simply go to Strings.xml and there on top right, you will find an option which says - "Open Editor". In editor, just type your translation of strings in another language(maybe English). This will make your app in both English and Spanish.

Comment: That would fix the problem for users that have their smartphone in English, but if they have it in French or German the problem will still be there.

Comment: But if you have a user in Germany or France, he would expect the app in German/French. So you have to provide translation for whatever country you want to support. What behavior are you expecting ? That the strings gets auto-converted to German and French?

Comment: It can be auto translated by Google automatically as well but I have never used the service. It is a paid service https://support.google.com/l10n/answer/6359997

Comment: I'm expecting that even if the user is French or German, the app will show the Spanish strings.

By the way, in Spain there's other regional languages rather than Spanish, and some users use that languages on their smartphones. There's no way to set Spanish as the default and only language for my app?

Comment: I believe if the user has that language on the phone, it should show the strings at least. It does show in mine, I tried even though mine has English as default. So if it doesn't show, that language is not on the phone. Or maybe it is phone specific.

Comment: I tried changing the system language to English or Catalan on two different devices, and both of them face the same problem: the strings are not showing (see image attached on original post). But if the devices are set in Spanish, the strings will show correctly.